# Why converting ESM to CommonJS is not simple find and replace?

Tags: node.js, commonjs, tsc, es6-modules

I've been working on a TypeScript project (for NodeJs environment) so I've been using ES module syntax for imports and exports. Using TSC with `"module": "commonjs", "esModuleInterop": true`, there is a lot of boilerplate code created such as:

```
var __importStar = (this && this.__importStar) || function (mod) {
    // omitted
};
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });

const path_1 = require("path"); // renamed identifier

const pug_1 = __importDefault(require("./template/pug"));
pug_1.default(...) // use of .default
```

So my question is, why we cannot simply convert ESM import/exports to plain `require` calls for NodeJs and why this boilerplate code and identifier renaming are needed?

For example, why following conversions cannot be done by a simple find-and-replace (with regex or some parsing):

```
import * as path from "path";
// const path = require("path");

import { resolve } from "path";
// const { resolve } = require("path");

export default class MyClass {...}
// module.exports = class MyClass {...}

export class MyClass {...}
// module.exports.MyClass = class MyClass {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a 1:1 mapping. For example, using the ES6 import/export syntax, you can export multiple symbols *and* a default symbol. To do the same thing in CommonJS, you'd need to start nesting the exported objects into other exported objects which could cause problems.

Comment: So if someone were to use the imports/exports in a consistent (no default exports) way, 1:1 conversions can be written, right?

Comment: @SudhanshuVishnoi yes and that is why Babel has the noInterop flag and typescript the esModuleInterop flag.